# Graphing Square Root Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me graph the following function:

$ y = 2 \sqrt{x + 4} − 2$

I am new to graphing square roots.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find", "Show") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post

Comment: @DonLarynx, the OP hasn't used any words of the imperative form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to graph this function would be to first notice what transformations have been applied to the parent graph.

Given $y=2\sqrt{x+4}-2$, we notice the following:

- The parent graph is the square root function: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
- There is a vertical stretch by a factor of $2$
- There is a horizontal translation by $4$ units to the left
- There is a vertical translation by $2$ units downwards

Knowing the transformations, can you apply these to the parent graph one by one in order to get your transformed function graph?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Finding the $y$-intercept and the $x$-intercept is a good start.

**$x$-intercept**: is where the graph cuts the $x$-axis also known as the roots of the equation.

$$0 = 2\sqrt {x+4} -2 \implies 0 = \sqrt{x+4} -1 \implies 0 = x + 4 -1 \implies x=-3$$

**$y$-intercept**: is where the graph cuts the $y$-axis.

$$y = 2\sqrt {0+4} -2 \implies y = 2\sqrt 4 -2 \implies y = 4 -2 = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Now the domain here is [-4,infinity) and the function is increasing and the range is [-2,infinity) and the graph starts at(-4,-2) , cuts x axis at(-4,0), y axis at (0,-2) and 
y tends to infinity as y tends to infinity. By using this you can easily draw the graph.